# What is a container in createjs?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs

What is the function of a container in createjs. What all createjs objects can be placed in a container? What animation effects can be implemented on a container? please post a link or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used CreateJS but there is an easelJS online documentation of the container class. EaselJS is part of the CreateJs Suite. It sais:

"A Container is a nestable display list that allows you to work with compound display elements. For example you could group arm, leg, torso and head Bitmap instances together into a Person Container, and transform them as a group, while still being able to move the individual parts relative to each other. Children of containers have their transform and alpha properties concatenated with their parent Container."

In the online documentation you can also see all methods, properties and events.

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html

Comment: Yep. Its just a group, which lets you move and transform child display objects together.